# jq extracting two fields from a json array

Tags: jq

I'm trying to extract two fields (id and name) from the following output using jq. I'm continually getting a compile error. I've tried jq .result.id|.name among other variations.

This is the output, I'm working with.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "6e55aff5ff4a74a234112c1d341b2e31",
      "zone_id": "d018a8f437462900bbe514c916a492a5",
      "zone_name": "example.com",
      "name": "example.com",
      "type": "A",
      "content": "98.158.193.66",
      "proxiable": true,
      "proxied": true,
      "ttl": 1,
      "locked": false,
      "meta": {
        "auto_added": false,
        "managed_by_apps": false,
        "managed_by_argo_tunnel": false,
        "source": "primary"
      },
      "created_on": "2020-09-14T12:48:23.952656Z",
      "modified_on": "2020-09-14T12:48:23.952656Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "3e1243be83fdaca735b419c224e670e7",
      "zone_id": "d018a8f437462900bbe514c916a492a5",
      "zone_name": "example.com",
      "name": "localhost.example.com",
      "type": "A",
      "content": "127.0.0.1",
      "proxiable": false,
      "proxied": false,
      "ttl": 14400,
      "locked": false,
      "meta": {
        "auto_added": false,
        "managed_by_apps": false,
        "managed_by_argo_tunnel": false,
        "source": "primary"
      },
      "created_on": "2020-09-14T12:17:53.68773Z",
      "modified_on": "2020-09-14T12:17:53.68773Z"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this: `jq '.result[] | .id , .name' data.json`.

The main problem with the other command you tried is that `result` is an array, so you need to specify to iterate over it before you're able to extract `id` and `name` from the elements inside the array.

*Also the json you posted misses a closing curly bracket `}`*